# Empty body in response when using request module in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am using request module and i am getting empty body in my response,here is the code

```html
        request.get(data_url, function (error, response,body)  {
            console.log('----@@@@@@----');
            console.log(response);
            console.log('----@@@@@@----');
            console.log(body);
```

actually when i manually hit the url contained in my data_url variable, a csv file gets downloaded automatically, is the problem due to this nature, if not please suggest a suitable solution.

Also if i replace the data_url with the actual url contained in the variable then i am getting the body part in response.

Comment: why i should use request.post also on using request.post i am facing the same problem, the main point here is whenever i am hitting the url manually or replacing the data_url with the actual url then in that case i am getting the body part in my response.
i dont understand its a bit strange for me.

Comment: check ```error``` in console.log. It is possible that there is an error. And if there is error we wiil now what to do next

Comment: @Krzysztof Sztompka, i checked it but i am not getting any errors either.